# Using a while loop to iterate over a range of integers

Tags: python, loops

How do I rewrite the first code to use a `while` loop instead of the given `for` loop? The output of the two programs should be the same.

```
num = 500
for j in range(30, 100): 
     if j > 70:
         num = num – 5   
     else:    
         num = num + 2    
     print(num)
print("program output is", num)
```

I have tried this but it does not work correctly:

```
num = 500
while j > 30 and j < 100: 
     if j > 70:
         num = num – 5   
     else:    
         num = num + 2    
     print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop automatically updates the loop variable (`j`) in every iteration.

In a `while` loop however, you have to assign a new value to the variable yourself, otherwise the loop will never end.

A `for` loop like

```
for j in range(a, b):
    # do something ...
```

is equivalent to this `while` loop:

```
j = a
while j < b:
    # do something ...
    j += 1
```

(Note that `j += 1` means the same as `j = j + 1`.)

In your case, you need to write:

```
num = 500
j = 30
while j < 100:
     if j > 70:
         num = num – 5
     else:
         num = num + 2
     print(num)
     j += 1
print("program output is", num)
```